# Snakemake Getting Checkpoint and Aggregate Function to Work

Tags: bioinformatics, snakemake

I'm having issue getting my snakemake aggregate command to work. My hope is to take a given GTF file, look for separate regions within the GTF and if found write these regions to a separate file. Thus, I'm unsure the number of output GTF files each input GTF file will create. In order to solve this problem I'm attempting to use a snakemake checkpoint.

To do this I wrote a brief script called `collapse_gtf_file.py` which simply takes in a GTF file, and generates N number of files corresponding to the number of individual regions found. So if given the file `test_regions.gtf` which had three regions, it would generate `test_regions_1.gtf, test_regions_2.gtf test_regions_3.gtf` respectivly.

After said seperation, all GTF files should be converted to fasta files, and the aggregated.

However, I have not been able to get my checkpoint command to work. I can get the example cases to work, yet when I try and build a larger pipeline around this checkpoint it breaks.

So far I've tried following the checkpoint tutorial found here https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefile/rules.html#dynamic-files

```
sample=config["samples"]
reference=config["reference"]

rule all:
    input:
    ¦   expand("string_tie_assembly/{sample}.gtf", sample=sample),
    ¦                                                                                                 expand("string_tie_assembly_merged/merged_{sample}.gtf",sample=sample),
    ¦   #expand("split_gtf_file/{sample}", sample=sample),
    ¦   #expand("lncRNA_fasta/{sample}.fa", sample=sample),
    ¦   "combined_fasta/all_fastas_combined.fa",
    ¦   "run_CPC2/cpc_calc_output.txt"

rule samtools_sort:
    input:
    ¦   "mapped_reads/{sample}.bam"
    output:
    ¦   "sorted_reads/{sample}.sorted.bam"
    shell:
    ¦   "samtools sort -T sorted_reads/{wildcards.sample} {input} > {output}"

rule samtools_index:
    input:
        "sorted_reads/{sample}.sorted.bam"
    output:
        "sorted_reads/{sample}.sorted.bam.bai"
    shell:
        "samtools index {input}"

rule generate_fastq:
    input:
        "sorted_reads/{sample}.sorted.bam"
    output:
        "fastq_reads/{sample}.fastq"
    shell:
        "samtools fastq {input} > {output}"

rule string_tie_assembly:
    input:
        "sorted_reads/{sample}.sorted.bam"
    output:
        "string_tie_assembly/{sample}.gtf"
    shell:
        "stringtie {input} -f 0.0 -a 0 -m 50 -c 3.0 -f 0.0 -o {output}"

rule merge_gtf_file_features:
    input:
    ¦   "string_tie_assembly/{sample}.gtf"
    output:
    ¦   "string_tie_assembly_merged/merged_{sample}.gtf"
    shell:
    ¦   #prevents errors when there's no sequence
    ¦   """
    ¦   set +e
    ¦   stringtie --merge -o {output} -m 25 -c 3.0 {input}
    ¦   exitcode=$?
    ¦   if [ $exitcode -eq 1 ]
    ¦   then
    ¦   ¦   exit 0
    ¦   else
    ¦   ¦   exit 0
    ¦   fi
    ¦   """

#This is where the issue seems to arise from. Modeled after https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefile/rules.html#dynamic-files 

checkpoint clustering:
    input:
    ¦   "string_tie_assembly_merged/merged_{sample}.gtf"
    output:
    ¦   clusters = directory("split_gtf_file/{sample}")
    shell:
    ¦   """
    ¦   mkdir -p split_gtf_file/{wildcards.sample} ;

    ¦   python collapse_gtf_file.py -gtf {input} -o split_gtf_file/{wildcards.sample}/{wildcards.sample}
    ¦   """

rule gtf_to_fasta:
    input:
    ¦   "split_gtf_file/{sample}/{sample}_{i}.gtf"
    output:
    ¦   "lncRNA_fasta/{sample}/canidate_{sample}_{i}.fa"
    wildcard_constraints:
    ¦   i="\d+"
    shell:
    ¦   "gffread -w {output} -g {reference} {input}"


def aggregate_input(wildcards):
    checkpoint_output = checkpoints.clustering.get(**wildcards).output[0]
    x = expand("lncRNA_fasta/{sample}/canidate_{sample}_{i}.fa",
    ¦   sample=wildcards.sample,
    ¦   i=glob_wildcards(os.path.join(checkpoint_output, "{i}.fa")).i)
    return x

rule combine_fasta_file:
    input:
    ¦   aggregate_input
    output:
    ¦   "combined_fasta/all_fastas_combined.fa"
    shell:
    ¦   "cat {input} > {output}"
```

```
Error Message:

InputFunctionException in combine_fasta_file:
WorkflowError: Missing wildcard values for sample
Wildcards:
```

What this seems to me is indicating that something is wrong with the way I've called wildcards above in the aggregate command, but I cannot figure out what. Any pointers would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `aggregate_input` is expecting variable `wildcards.sample`, but you don't have any wildcards specified in `rule combine_fasta_file`. You may want to either specify the wildcard in that rule or refactor the function to use global variable, if applicable.

Comment: Thank you for your input, but I don't think this is the cause. Based off the code found https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#dynamic-files - it appears that the command that combines all files (here `combine_fasta_file`) shouldn't need any wildcards. Or am I misunderstanding your point?

Comment: Your link is about `dynamic()` but it is not used in your code. Are you talking referring to [`checkpoint`](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#data-dependent-conditional-execution) instead?

Comment: Yes! My mistake, here is the correct link. https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#data-dependent-conditional-execution . I also updated the question with an example that I have gotten to run in isolation.

Comment: Removed the test case. That was just an example of something that I had gotten to work which was very similar. Still having the same issue/error

Comment: Are you sure absence of wildcards in `output` is not the problem? The code in your link about [checkpoint](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#data-dependent-conditional-execution) depends on the wildcard `sample` in `rule aggregate`.

Comment: Yes!! This was it. So I think my issue can be summed up in I was attempting to use my `rule combine_fasta_file` to aggregate multiple steps. Instead I needed to gather all `.fa` files first, and THEN aggregate all `.fa` files from different samples. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1):

The rule that gathers the output of the checkpoint (`combine_fasta_file`, in your case) needs to contain the wildcards present in the output of the checkpoint rule (`clustering`, in your case). This is because Snakemake looks at your desired output, then tries to work its way backwards through your rules to the input files available. If the wildcards at the gathering rule to not include the wildcards of the checkpoint rule, the precise checkpoint being referred to could be ambiguous.

To elaborate on the comments of the [Snakemake docs checkpoint example](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#data-dependent-conditional-execution) by Manavalan Gajapathy and the multiple aggregations required by pabster212, I've generated a minimal example to highlight checkpoints and multi-gathering.

Input setup:

```
mkdir -p input/sampleA_run{1,2,3}
mkdir -p input/sampleB_run{4,5}
touch input/sampleA_run1/{apple,banana,cucumber,beet,basil}.txt
touch input/sampleA_run2/{alpha,beta,gamma}.txt
touch input/sampleA_run3/{red,blue,green,brown}.txt
touch input/sampleB_run4/{alice,betty,beth,barbara,christy}.txt
touch input/sampleB_run5/{alex,brad,bart,bennett,clive}.txt
```

Snakefile that steps through checkpoints and multi-aggregation:

```
rule all:
    input:
        # Final
        expand("output/gathered_samples/{sample}.txt", sample = ["sampleA","sampleB"])

# My real-world analysis at this step (Nanopore guppy basecaller) 
# Takes as input a directory 
# With a inconsistent numbers of files and names for files (.fast5 in real analysis)
# Due to filtering, there are more inputs than outputs (.fastq in real analysis)
# And the output filenames are not predictably named or numbered
# Therefore I use a checkpoint to evaluate which output files have been created
# In this toy example, only files beginning with 'b' are maintained
checkpoint unpredictable_file_generator:
    input:
        "input/{sample}_{run_id}"
    output:
        directory("output/unpredictable_files/{sample}_{run_id}"),
    shell:
        """
        mkdir -p {output}

        for some_file in {input}/*
        do
            outfile=$(basename "$some_file")
            if [[ "$outfile" =~ ^b.* ]]
            then
                touch "{output}/$outfile"
            fi
        done
        """

# For my real-world analysis, this intermediate step 
# Represents generation of bams from fastqs
# No intermediate step is necessarily required following the checkpoint
# Just modify the input-gathering function below (gather_from_checkpoint) 
# To expand 'output/unpredictable_files' instead of 'output/intermediate_files'
rule intermediate_step:
    input:
        "output/unpredictable_files/{sample}_{run_id}/{file_id}.txt"
    output:
        "output/intermediate_files/{sample}_{run_id}/{file_id}.txt"
    shell:
        """
        cp {input} {output}
        """

# Function to gather all outputs from checkpoint rule
# The output of the rule referring back to the checkpoint (gather_one, below)
# Must contain the all wildcards in the checkpoint rule
# To gather further (e.g. gather by sample rather than by run_id)
# An additional gather rule is required
def gather_from_checkpoint(wildcards):
    checkpoint_output = checkpoints.unpredictable_file_generator.get(**wildcards).output[0]
    return expand("output/intermediate_files/{sample}_{run_id}/{file_id}.txt",
           sample=wildcards.sample,
           run_id=wildcards.run_id,
           file_id=glob_wildcards(os.path.join(checkpoint_output, "{file_id}.txt")).file_id)

# Gathers all files by run_id
# But each sample is still divided into runs
# For my real-world analysis, this could represent a 'samtools merge bam'
rule gather_one:
    input:
        gather_from_checkpoint
    output:
        "output/gathered_runs/{sample}_{run_id}.txt"
    shell:
        """
        # Generate a file for each run 
        # Containing the names of all files output by 'unknown_file_generator' 
        echo {input} | tr ' ' $'\\n' > {output}
        """

# Gathers all previously-run_id-gathered files by sample
# For my real-world analysis, this could represent a second 'samtools merge bam'
# After which point the first merge could potentially be removed if it were marked 'temporary'
############
# Note wildcard restriction was required 
# To prevent the {run_id} match from descending into diretories
# And generating 'ChildIOException' errors
rule gather_two:
    input:
        lambda wildcards: expand("output/gathered_runs/{sample}_{run_id}.txt",
            sample = wildcards.sample,
            run_id = glob_wildcards("input/" + wildcards.sample + "_{run_id,[^/]+}/").run_id)
    output:
        "output/gathered_samples/{sample}.txt"
    shell:
        """
        # This output should contain 6 filenames for each sample
        # Each beginning with 'b'
        cat {input} > {output}
        """
```